# Выделить цветом дубликаты значений во всех листах книги

Tags: excel, vba

Есть макрос для выделения и подсветки дубликатов *в выделенном диапазоне ячеек* Excel.

Мне нужно, чтобы он выделял дубликаты *во всей книге*, даже если они на разных листах. Т.е. чтобы массивом был не выделенный диапазон, а все заполненные ячейки на всех листах. Вот сам макрос:

```
Sub ColorsDoubles()
    On Error Resume Next
    ' массив цветов, используемых для заливки ячеек-дубликатов
    Colors = Array(12900829, 15849925, 14408946, 14610923, 15986394, 14281213, 14277081, _
                   9944516, 14994616, 12040422, 12379352, 15921906, 14336204, 15261367, 14281213)

    Dim coll As New Collection, dupes As New Collection, _
        cols As New Collection, ra As Range, cell As Range, n&
    Err.Clear: Set ra = Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    If Err Then Exit Sub

    ra.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone: Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each cell In ra.Cells ' запонимаем значение дубликатов в коллекции dupes
    Err.Clear: If Len(Trim(cell)) Then coll.Add CStr(cell.Value), CStr(cell.Value)
        If Err Then dupes.Add CStr(cell.Value), CStr(cell.Value)
    Next cell
    For i& = 1 To dupes.Count ' заполняем коллекцию cols цветами для разных дубликатов
    n = n Mod (UBound(Colors) + 1): cols.Add Colors(n), dupes(i): n = n + 1
    Next
    For Each cell In ra.Cells ' окрашиваем ячейки, если для её значения назначен цвет
    cell.Interior.Color = cols(CStr(cell.Value)) ' если надо окрасить всю строку,то cell.EntireRow.Interior.color = cols(CStr(cell.Value))
    Next cell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

По комментарию ниже сделал - не получилось.

```
Sub ColorsDoubles()
    On Error Resume Next
    ' массив цветов, используемых для заливки ячеек-дубликатов
    Colors = Array(12900829, 15849925, 14408946, 14610923, 15986394, 14281213, 14277081, _
                   9944516, 14994616, 12040422, 12379352, 15921906, 14336204, 15261367, 14281213)

    Dim coll As New Collection, dupes As New Collection, _
        cols As New Collection, ra As Range, cell As Range, n&
    For Each oneSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Err.Clear: Set ra = oneSheet.UsedRange
    Next
    If Err Then Exit Sub

    ra.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone: Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each cell In ra.Cells ' запонимаем значение дубликатов в коллекции dupes
    Err.Clear: If Len(Trim(cell)) Then coll.Add CStr(cell.Value), CStr(cell.Value)
        If Err Then dupes.Add CStr(cell.Value), CStr(cell.Value)
    Next cell
    For i& = 1 To dupes.Count ' заполняем коллекцию cols цветами для разных дубликатов
    n = n Mod (UBound(Colors) + 1): cols.Add Colors(n), dupes(i): n = n + 1
    Next
    For Each cell In ra.Cells ' окрашиваем ячейки, если для её значения назначен цвет
    cell.Interior.Color = cols(CStr(cell.Value)) ' если надо окрасить всю строку,то cell.EntireRow.Interior.color = cols(CStr(cell.Value))
    Next cell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Все окрасило одним цветом. Применяю в этом файле: https://yadi.sk/d/XbjB8sE9f8qkBQ.

В нем надо выделить те артикулы, которые повторяются на других листах. Файл с кодом: https://yadi.sk/i/vt7kK9hJN7e5Pg

Я что-то делаю не так?

Comment: Насчёт всех ячеек одного листа - это тупо `Set ra = worksheet.UsedRange`. Ну а по листам - это надо `For Each oneSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets`. PS. Код мог бы и отформатировать - на такой лапше глаза сломать можно, и ни хрена не видать.

Comment: Про форматирование прошу прощения... У меня все отформатированным отображается...
В итоге получается вот так?
`For Each oneSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Err.Clear: Set ra = Worksheet.UsedRange
    Next
    If Err Then Exit Sub`
Или я что-то напутал?

Comment: Нет, Worksheet - имя класс, а Вам нужна ссылка на конкретный текущий лист. Так что `Set ra = oneSheet.UsedRange`

Comment: Все окрасило одним цветом. Применяю в этом файле https://yadi.sk/d/XbjB8sE9f8qkBQ. В нем нодо выделить те артикулы, которые повторяются на других листах

Comment: Зачем проверять все ячейки? Данные настолько неструктурированы и хаотично расположены? При нормальной структуре данных поиск можно вести гораздо эффективнее. И зачем эта попугаистая заливка? Одного цвета мало?

Comment: Артикулы могут быть в произвольных колонках в рамках определенного диапазона, как и компаньоны.По первоначальной задумке, каждый артикул, встречающийся более 1 раза должен был быть подсвечен своим уникальным цветом, чтобы его сразу было видно. Но, если это труднореализуемо, то спасет и информация о дублях артикулов как на разных листах, так и на одном.

Answer (score 0):

В цикле каждый из листов книги выбираем как лист-образец, сверяем его значения со значениями всех листов (включая лист-образец)...

Без оптимизации. Листы-образцы не исключаются из дальнейшей проверки и заливка ячеек может повторяться по несколько раз. На результат не влияет, но - дополнительное время на обработку.

```
Sub ColorsDoubles()
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim rRng1 As Range, rRng2 As Range, c1 As Range, c2 As Range
    Dim lColor As Long

    lColor = RGB(250, 150, 150)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each sht1 In Worksheets
        Set rRng1 = sht1.UsedRange
        
        For Each sht2 In Worksheets
            Set rRng2 = sht2.UsedRange
            
            For Each c1 In rRng1
                If c1.Value <> "" Then
                    For Each c2 In rRng2
                        If c1.Address <> c2.Address Then
                            If c1.Value = c2.Value Then c2.Interior.Color = lColor
                        End If
                    Next c2
                End If
            Next c1
        Next sht2
    Next sht1
    
    Set rRng1 = Nothing: Set rRng2 = Nothing           
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Как вариант ускорения: создать массив с именами листов.

В примере красным закрашиваются ячейки, у которых есть дубли или на этом же листе, или на следующих. Зеленые - последние дублированные значения.

```
Sub ColorsDoubles()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim aNameSheets()
    Dim rRng1 As Range, rRng2 As Range, c1 As Range, c2 As Range
    Dim lCountSheets As Long, lColor1 As Long, lColor2 As Long
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    
    lCountSheets = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    ReDim aNameSheets(1 To lCountSheets)
    
    For Each sht In Worksheets
         n = n + 1
    
         With sht
             aNameSheets(n) = .Name 'имя листа в массив' 
             .UsedRange.Interior.Pattern = xlNone 'удаление заливки на листе'
         End With
     Next sht
    
    lColor1 = RGB(200, 150, 150) 'цвета'
    lColor2 = RGB(150, 200, 150)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 1 To lCountSheets
        Set rRng1 = Worksheets(aNameSheets(i)).UsedRange 'диапазон листа-образца'
        
        For n = i To lCountSheets
            Set rRng2 = Worksheets(aNameSheets(n)).UsedRange 'диапазоны следующих листов'
            
            For Each c1 In rRng1
                If c1.Value <> "" Then 'если значение в ячейке-образце есть'
                    For Each c2 In rRng2
                        If i = n And c1.Address = c2.Address Then
                        Else 'если сравнивается не сама с собой'
                            If c1.Value = c2.Value Then 'если значения совпали'
                                c1.Interior.Color = lColor1 'красим'
                                c2.Interior.Color = lColor2
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next c2
                End If
            Next c1
        Next n
    Next i
                
    Set rRng1 = Nothing: Set rRng2 = Nothing 'освобождаем память'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: vikttur, спасибо, по коду вижу, что варианты интересные, но оба намертво завесили Excel, а потому опробовать не получилось.

Comment: Работа с цветом (как и любым форматированием ячеек) медленная. Отказаться от этого и определять дубли другими способами. Например, запись в массив и последующая выгрузка на лист данных об артикулах и местах их нахождения.

Comment: По Вашему наказу публикую ниже то, что помогло решить задачу.

Answer (score 0):

Мою проблему мне помогли решить [тут](https://www.planetaexcel.ru/forum/index.php?PAGE_NAME=message&FID=1&TID=139980&TITLE_SEO=139980-skvoznoy-poisk-i-podsvetka-dublikatov-v-knige&PAGEN_1=2)

Вот решение, пусть и не совсем такое, как изначально предполагалось. Данный макрос ищет дубликаты в столбце с заданным именем и выводит список значений с указанием их местоположений.

```
Sub UniqArticul()
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim iLastRow As Long
Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim ColArticul As Integer
Dim dict As Object
Dim arr
Dim Col As String

Col = Application.InputBox("Укажите название столбца", , , , , , , 2)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "Дубликаты"

   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"): dict.comparemode = 1
  For Each Sht In Worksheets
    If Sht.Name <> "Дубликаты" Then
      With Sht
       Set FoundCell = .Rows(1).Find(Col, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
          ColArticul = FoundCell.Column
          iLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColArticul).End(xlUp).Row
          arr = .Range(.Cells(2, ColArticul), .Cells(iLastRow, ColArticul))
          For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
            dict.Item(arr(i, 1)) = dict.Item(arr(i, 1)) + Sht.Name & " строка: " & i + 1 & "; "
          Next
        End If
        Set FoundCell = Nothing
      End With
    End If
  Next
   Columns("C:D").ClearContents
   Range("C1").Resize(dict.Count, 2) = Application.Transpose(Array(dict.keys, dict.Items))
End Sub
```